# Installing mod_wsgi into XAMPP on OSX Lion

Tags: macos, osx-lion, xampp, mod-wsgi

I am trying to configure XAMPP 1.7.3 on OSX 10.7.2 Lion to use mod_wsgi 3.3. Here is what I am doing:

1. Installed XAMPP for OSX 1.7.3 and the Developer Package. All is running well at this point.
2. Downloaded and extracted http://modwsgi.googlecode.com/files/mod_wsgi-3.3.tar.gz
3. `./configure`
4. `make`
5. `sudo make install`
6. This copies the compiled mod_wsgi.so file into the OSX apache, but I want it in XAMPP, so I copy:
   `sudo cp /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/modules/`
7. Add the module to the XAMPP httpd.conf `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so`
8. Start XAMPP Apache, I get the following notice in the error_log:

   `[notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.1 PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations`

When I visit http://localhost, i get this error (via Chrome):

```
`Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.`
```

and this error is printed to the error_log:

```
 `[notice] child pid 22847 exit signal Bus error (10)`
```

I don't know how to troubleshoot this error or what I am missing. Any insight is appreciated!!

**UPDATE**

I found a blog [here](http://www.mals.me/2011/10/running-django-with-xampp-on-os-x.html) that discusses using apache extensions module with this command:

`./configure --with-apxs=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/apxs --with-python=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7`

The configure looks good, but I get this compiler error:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/apxs -c -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DENABLE_DTRACE  -Wc,'-arch i386' -Wc,'-arch ppc' mod_wsgi.c -Wl,-F/System/Library/Frameworks -framework Python -u _PyMac_Error /System/Library/Frameworks/  -arch i386 -arch ppc -ldl  -framework CoreFoundation  
Use of assignment to $[ is deprecated at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/apxs line 86.
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/build/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -prefer-pic -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include -L/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -arch i386 -arch ppc  -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -no-cpp-precomp  -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include  -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include   -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include -arch i386 -arch ppc -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DENABLE_DTRACE  -c -o mod_wsgi.lo mod_wsgi.c && touch mod_wsgi.slo
llvm-gcc-4.2: error trying to exec '/usr/bin/../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/powerpc-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2': execvp: No such file or directory
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/tmp//cco5iCcm.out
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use --with-apxs option to configure to make it use the apxs from XAMPP distro. If they don't supply one so as to be able to compile extra Apache modules, then the XAMPP distro can't be used.

In other words, you need to compile mod_wsgi against the Apache you want to use, not a different one.

Go read about --with-apxs in instructions:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide#Configuring_The_Source_Code

Comment: Thanks Graham! I found [this](http://www.mals.me/2011/10/running-django-with-xampp-on-os-x.html) that gives an example of that: `./configure --with-apxs=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/apxs --with-python=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7`... but I get a compiler error. I'll put the text into an edit question.

Comment: You probably didn't need --with-python if Python 2.7 is system wide default Python. If it isn't, then you likely could have referred to /usr/bin/python2.7 instead. As for compilation error, possibly connected with first error in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/apxs. Ask the XAMPP why their apxs is failing.